# How can I Invoke a Gradle script from Java?

Tags: java, gradle

I am looking for a Java API to invoke Gradle.

Something similar to what's available for Ant or Maven.
Could not find such reference. Help..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Gradle Tooling API. See [Embedding Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#embedding) in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the samples in the full Gradle distribution.